# Fraction of graphs with bound on number of perfect matchings

Tags: co.combinatorics, asymptotics, bipartite-graphs, perfect-matchings, matching-theory

Asymptotically what is the fraction of balanced bipartite graph on $2n$ vertices with at most $cn^{\beta}$ edges having at most $n^\alpha$ perfect matchings for any fixed $c,\alpha>0$ and fixed $\beta\in[1,1.5]$?

Comment: Perhaps you could get a lower bound on this quantity using Brègman's Theorem. It would give you a set of degree sequences that are guaranteed to have a small number of perfect matchings (you'd still have to count balanced bipartite graphs with those degree sequences, though).

Comment: @JonNoel I am unfamiliar with this theorem. Perhaps you could elaborate below.

Comment: It is Theorem 1 in this paper: http://www.combinatorics.org/ojs/index.php/eljc/article/view/v18i1p10. Like I said, this can only give you a lower bound on the ratio that you are interested in and it's very possible that the bound won't be very good!

Comment: @JonNoel Seems like it.